# Can I host free government or bank forms on my website?

Tags: copyright, india, fair-use

If I host government forms or any other free forms on my website just for consolidation or ease-of-access, could I face any legal issues?

I live in India.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the creator of the forms disclaims copyright then you legally need permission to post/host copies.

Some governments (e.g., the U.S. government) disclaim copyright protection for their documents.

Hosting forms that are posted for free with no access restrictions (e.g., clickwrap) *might* be covered under "fair use," but I do not know the Indian law on that.